# How to add a value inside a string

Tags: r, regex, string

How can I add a value inside a string when a condition is met.

For example, take the following data:

```
my_data <- c("ab 93 1455 1863 2713 sb 673 771 1601 1969", 
             "ab 93 1098 1455 2423 2427 sb 168 673 1256", 
             "ab 93 1098; sb 1256")
```

I want to add a ";" when a number proceeds a character.

Therefore, I would like the output to be:

```
output<- c("ab 93 1455 1863 2713; sb 673 771 1601 1969", 
           "ab 93 1098 1455 2423 2427; sb 168 673 1256", 
           "ab 93 1098; sb 1256")
```

If this solution could be completed in the context of a data frame that would be great.

So far, I have been able to detect the condition I'm interested in using the following code:

```
str_detect(my_data, "[0-9] [a-z]")
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

But I am having trouble moving beyond this point.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, use regular expressions:

```
output <- gsub("(\\d)( +[a-zA-Z])", "\\1;\\2", my_data)

print(output)

# [1] "ab 93 1455 1863 2713; sb 673 771 1601 1969" "ab 93 1098 1455 2423 2427; sb 168 673 1256"
# [3] "ab 93 1098; sb 1256"
```

Answer (score 1):

Or another option using lookarounds, asserting a digit to the left and 1 or more spaces to the right followed by a char a-zA-Z:

```
my_data <- c("ab 93 1455 1863 2713 sb 673 771 1601 1969", 
             "ab 93 1098 1455 2423 2427 sb 168 673 1256", 
             "ab 93 1098; sb 1256")

gsub("(?<=\\d)(?= +[a-zA-Z])", ";", my_data, perl=T)

[1] "ab 93 1455 1863 2713; sb 673 771 1601 1969"
[2] "ab 93 1098 1455 2423 2427; sb 168 673 1256"
[3] "ab 93 1098; sb 1256"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZItvTb/1) | [R demo](https://tio.run/##fY6xDoIwGIT3PsWlUxsh4W@hpQFCfAcnxZgCxkUTAzroy1dATZy84Zvuu9wQwuVx6P3No4zRCe5bOA1KswyUGw1lSWNsYayGtQQyyQRnHI/A8Juvmrj87atU6Rl29snkywapzPxTi6U8lyRjp/HeCi7qsmqaXoq6wmrn4@c63u7lNMKLCZ/7Ea7H4VxtJAvhBQ)